# swift async await pause task and waiting for some data

Tags: swift, async-await

I need to do infinity load while device not connected to the internet

Example: if user lost the internet connection when the app doing a request then app must waiting while internet connection will restore and trying again to do the request

I do it with the completions

```
func getData(completion: ((SomeData?) -> Void)?) {
    apiService.getSomeData() { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            return data
        case .failure(let error):
            switch error {
            case .networkError:
                let getDataTask: () -> Void = {
                    self?.getData()
                }

                // when internet connection will be restore then execute all tasks from onConnectionToTheInternetRestoredTasks
                self?.onConnectionToTheInternetRestoredTasks.append(getDataTask)
            default:
                throw error
            }
        }
    }
}

private func onConnectionToTheInternetRestored() {
    onConnectionToTheInternetRestoredTasks.forEach { $0() }
    onConnectionToTheInternetRestoredTasks = []
}
```

but now I need to refactor it in async/await

```
func getData() async throws -> SomeData {
    let result = await apiService.getSomeData()
    switch result {
    case .success(let data):
        return data
    case .failure(let error):
        switch error {
        case .networkError:
            // need to do wating for restore and try again
        default:
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to process `.networkError` in `getData() async throws` to waiting for restore connection

Can u please explain it to me ?

Comment: Have you tried setting [`waitsForConnectivity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/2908812-waitsforconnectivity)? Seems like it would be much easier…

Comment: @Rob wow! I didn't know about it, thank you! I will try